# ADF navigate to same view / page

Tags: java, oracle-adf

**Proconditions:**
I don´t use ADF business components. 
Only ADFFaces and binding.

**Problem**:
I hava a problem navigating from one view to itself.

I have following items:

**Taskflow1**: 
Contains *Taskflow2* and *Taskflow3*. Whern clicking on button b1 in view1 Taskflow2 navigates to Taskflow3.

**Taskflow2** and **Taskflow3**: 
Contain the same view *view1*.

**view1**: 
In *view1* there are inputFields and a *button b1* which should open *view1* again but without the current binding (--> Data which was typed before).

So the goal is that the inputFields and so on are empty after clicking on b1.

I think the problem is that there is no page refresh. 
If I navigate to another view view2 and then call TaskFlow1 or TaskFlow2 the binding is not there and everything works fine. 
But navigating to another page is no option in this case.

I have already tried that taskflow1 only calls itself when clicking button b1.

Comment: What do you mean Taskflow2 and Taskflow3 contain the same view? Do they include the same .jsff? If yes where does the .jsff take the values of the inputs, from a backing bean? You can post some code pieces to make clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by defining partialTriggers on the inputfields. 
The trigger is a button on the page which leaves the taskflow.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set partialTrigger on the i/p field. Also you would have to immediate="true" so that validation is not fired on the other components.
On the iterator, you would have to set the refresh condition to "ifNeeded" so that when the iterator re-loads once the page has been invoked again, it would have the new set of values.
Feel free to post any queries.